# Combine two Laravel collections with alternating rows

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel

I have two Laravel collections, which are the result of database queries (with Eloquent ORM).

I wish to combine the two collections, with alternating rows from each collection.

So if collection 1 was:
One, Two, Three, Four

And collection 2 was:
Aardvark, Bottle, Cat, Dog

The result would be:
One, Aardvark, Two, Bottle, Three, Cat, Four, Dog.

Optionally it would also be nice to alternate two (or three) at a time e.g.
One, Two, Aardvark, Bottle, Three, Four, Cat, Dog.

Thanks.

Comment: What get collections and make new collection in a loop?

Answer (score 0):

If you already have the collections, probably easiest is to just loop on them and add to a new collection or array.  This gives you fine level control on the ability to alternate two or three or whatever at a time:

Since I can't see your code, I'll put in a pseudo code example to help illustrate:

```
alternator = 1;
choiceOfAlternate = 3; // Every third for example on this second array/collection
arrayOfStuff = [];
for (loop = 1; loop < size of collection; loop ++){
   if(choiceOfAlternate === 3){  // You could use mod here too, just showing simplest
     arrayOfStuff[] = [itemAtIndex*loop*OfFirstCollection, itemAt*Alternator*OfSecondCollection];
     choiceOfAlternate = 1;  // start your alternate loop again
     alternator ++; // So you have an index on the second collection that doesn't start over
  }else{
     // You'll have to decide if you want an array in here, or null, or whatever
     arrayOfStuff[] = [itemAtIndex*loop*OfFirstCollection, ''];
     choiceOfAlternate ++;
  }
```

There are numerous ways to skin this cat, but sometimes the oldschool method is easiest to follow.